# Error while getting Entity using getObjectById : javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: No such object

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am using [JDO on app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries). For some reason the method `getObjectById` of `PersistenceManager` returns:

```
No such object
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusObjectNotFoundException: No such object
```

**code:**

```
public Image getById(long id) {
        Image img = null;
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            img = (Image) pm.getObjectById(id);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            pm.close();
        }
        return img;
    }
```

In other part of this file I am able to successfully retrieve all Entities using `Query`:

```
 public List<Image> getAll() {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        List<Image> results = null;
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Image.class);
        q.setOrdering("date desc");
        try {
            results = (List<Image>) q.execute();
        } finally {
            q.closeAll();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

**Debugging:**
[image]
[image]

It's shown/obvious that datastore holds the object with requested `id`. Why this exception is being thrown?

Comment: No, it shows clearly that the datastore has a specific "table" with a column with that id long value. Since you didn't tell it the "table" to look at it, how is it to know where to look? See the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the class of the object that you are trying to retrieve.

So, the typical signature of that method should be something like:

`getObjectById(Class arg0, Object arg1);`

where arg0 is the class that you are trying to retrieve i.e. `Image.class` and arg1 is the key value object.